# .NET Assembly Resolve

Tags: c#, versioning, .net-assembly

Are dependent assemblies loaded only when they are required?

Say I have an assembly **Test.dll** which refers to **SharedTest.dll (version 2.0.0.0, strongly typed)**.

**Test.dll** has many classes within it. But only one class say **Foo.cs** actually uses the SharedTest.dll. The same class Foo.cs has two **static methods** which is actually used by my assembly and these static methods have **nothing to do with SharedTest.dll**
Does the CLR still load SharedTest.dll?

The reason I am confused is I am **not getting** an assembly resolution exception even if my application root folder has **version 4.0.0.0 of SharedTest.dll** deployed. My application seems to work fine even if there is **no version 2.0.0.0 of SharedTest.dll**

Note:

1. SharedTest.dll is not in GAC too
2. The Foo.cs is decorated with an attribute. This attribute is defined in SharedTest.dll

Thanks in advance

Comment: The simple explanation is that you never actually call a method that is stored in SharedTest.dll.  The just-in-time compiler only loads assemblies when it has to.  Just in time.

Comment: Forgot to mention. I have decorated the class Foo.cs with an attribute. The attribute is defined in SharedTest.dll. Does JIT still not load assembly in this case?

Comment: Same reason, if nobody calls Type.GetCustomAttributes() then it isn't needed.  Use Fuslogvw.exe and log all binds to obtain facts instead of guesses.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you very much. Clear now. If u want to put that as an answer i can mark it as an answer. May be helpful for someone